# How to I tell Rust where to look for a static library?

Tags: rust

Is there any way to tell Rust where to look for my static library? Example code

```
#[link(name = "/this/is/the/path/libfoo.a", kind = "static")]
```

If not, what config change can I make or what folder do I place my library in so that I can use it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`rustc` invokes the system linker which looks for all libraries specified in `#[link(...)]` in library directories. There are usually several default library directories (like `/lib` and `/usr/lib` on Linux), and more can be specified via linker flags (`rustc` accepts `-L` options which it then passes through to the linker).

If you invoke `rustc` directly, you can use the `-L` option to add additional library directories which will be then passed through to the linker. If you use Cargo, however, you've got a few more options:

- Cargo adds the `/target/<profile>/deps` directory as a library source directory.
- You can use `cargo rustc`

  ```
  cargo rustc -- -L /path/to/library/directory
  ```
- You can specify the `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable:

  ```
  RUSTFLAGS='-L /path/to/library/directory' cargo build
  ```
- You can use a build script to [output more linker options](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#outputs-of-the-build-script)

  ```
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=foo");
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/path/to/foo");
  ```

The easiest way for you, I think, is to add [a custom build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) which will copy or create a symlink to your library in the corresponding `/target/<profile>/deps` directory.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Cargo but after placing my libs inside `<project_root>/build`, `<project_root>/build/native/*`, & `<project_root>/deps`, I still can not get it to work :( Error: `could not find native static library 'demo', perhaps an -L flag is missing?`. My lib name is `libdemo.a`

Comment: I'm very sorry, I meant `target/<whatever directory>`, not `build/`. I don't know why I wrote `build/` :( Also you can't just put your files there, this directory is a kind of erased before each build. You need the build script to do it for you. See [here](https://github.com/netvl/pub-rust-cargo-external-libs-example), for example.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the accepted answer, what worked for me is as following:

- under *debug* build, putting dependency files under `target/debug/deps` worked; but putting files under `target/debug/native/*` did not seem to work.

Cargo seems to only look under `target/debug/deps` by default.

You can run with `cargo build --verbose` to see the verbose `rustc` commands and the options used. `-L` option specifies additional link dependency directory.

Comment: `cargo build --verbose` [doesn't show the actual linker command](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38206), so that's of dubious usefulness. Anyway, I've updated the accepted answer to no longer be factually inaccurate.

Comment: With `cargo` _(v0.26.0)_ that I'm using, it does indicate the `-L` option for the `rustc` command under `verbose` mode. The [github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38206) is probably already fixed.

Comment: No, that's the command *to `rustc`*, not the command *to the linker*.