# How can I link a Rust Wasm application with libpq via wasm-pack?

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-diesel, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

I'm trying to create a NodeJS application with a Wasm database layer. I use Rust, Diesel as a database driver and `wasm-pack` as a WebAssembly compiler.

When I try to build my service with `wasm-pack`, it fails trying to link the `libpq` library. The `PQ_LIB_DIR` environment variable is set, and the `diesel-cli` works without any issue, but when I try to compile my service it fails with the following error:

```
error: linking with `rust-lld` failed: exit code: 1
  = note: rust-lld: error: unable to find library -llibpq
```

How can I fix it?

My system:

- **OS**: Windows 10
- **Rust**: 1.38.0
- **wasm-pack**: 0.8.1
- **diesel**: 1.4.0
- **PostgreSQL**: 12

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to link to a system library from WebAssembly. You have to use an implementation written in pure Rust code to make it work. You also could use a JavaScript library. But it always has to be inside of the JavaScript runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

libpq is available inside the postgreSQL installation binary

For example, [PosgreSQL Binary Download Site](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries) if open the zip distribution `postgresql-12.0-1-windows-x64-binaries.zip` you can see these 2 files:

- `pgsql\lib\libpq.dll`
- `pgsql\lib\libpq.lib`

You need to specify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or you can specify the -L in the compiler arguments to tell the folder path which will auto pick those files

If you have used the installer the same file should be there inside the installation folder

You can also refer this stackoverflow link [How to I tell Rust where to look for a static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246849/how-to-i-tell-rust-where-to-look-for-a-static-library)

--EDIT--

To combine a C library inside a web assemble distribution, we can use this guide - 
[Compiling an Existing C Module to WebAssembly](http://try%20this%20guide%20to%20combine%20a%20c%20library%20inside%20wasm%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/existing_C_to_wasm)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help. Moreover, the `-L` option that leads to the PostgreSQL directory existed from the very start via the `PQ_LIB_DIR` but `lld` continue failing. Somewhere I have seen the idea that `libpq` should be WASM-complied as well; otherwise, the linker would be unable to find it. Probably, it is an answer.

Comment: yes, if you wanted run something browser then it needs to be embedded in the wasm binary distribution as static library