# rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lpq

Tags: postgresql, rust, webassembly, rust-diesel, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to build a simple web app using Yew, Diesel, and Postgres. When I run

```sh
wasm-pack build --target web --out-name wasm --out-dir ./static
```

I get the following error:

```
*rust-lld: error: unable to find library -lpq*
```

I'm on macOS Catalina. I installed Postgres through Homebrew. My `libpq.dylib` file is at `/usr/local/lib`.

These are the troubleshooting I've tried already:

1. Added `/usr/local/lib` to `$PATH`. My `pg_config` shows `LIBDIR = /usr/local/lib`.
2. Re-installed Postgres
3. Updated `rustc -nightly`

Ideas here are not helpful as well: [How can I link a Rust Wasm application with libpq via wasm-pack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58681067/how-can-i-link-a-rust-wasm-application-with-libpq-via-wasm-pack)

Still it is not resolved. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you really intend to link your frontend code to Postgres? How would that work, considering WASM does not support OS primitives that libpq would need (sockets and such)?

Comment: Hey, you are right. I should approach it with Rocket or Actix-web. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libpq does not support the wasm-web platform as far as I'm aware therefore there is no way to make this work. As already mentioned in the comments you probably want to use `diesel` in your backend code, not in the frontend.