# cargo build-bpf fails on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm, rust, solana

rustc --version = rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)

solana --version = solana-cli 1.10.8 (src:623ac656; feat:1122441720)

npm --version =  8.5.1

node --version = v12.22.9

os: ubuntu 22.04 lts

after i run: "[npm run build:program-rust](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld)" i am getting this error.

> /home/[user]/.rustup/toolchains/bpf/bin/cargo: error while loading
> shared libraries:libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory

same problem with anchor.[image]

i have located libssl0.1.1 there will it help me?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have the shared object on your system, `cargo build-bpf` is probably not finding it since it isn't in a standard path.  You can try the solutions at [How to I tell Rust where to look for a static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246849/how-to-i-tell-rust-where-to-look-for-a-static-library) to tell the linker where to find the library.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, libssl was upgraded to version 2.19. So I fixed the issue by running the following commands:

> wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb
> sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

yes, cargo wasn't in a standard path.
and fixed everything by reinstalling Linux.
it was Ubuntu for testing.
actually moved to Debian reinstalled packages and working properly.

Comment: oh only reinstalling linux, no biggie LOL
What command did you use to install cargo when it worked?